# Android Studio after upgrade errors "Gradle sync failed: ..."

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My app build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.marcus.exceltest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poiooxml:4.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
}
```

My Gradle build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Gradle.properties

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

The Error:

ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:
The project 'Exceltest' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.2 and sync project

The project 'Exceltest' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

The Event Log:
18:27   Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. (950 ms)

18:27   NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

18:28   Error running 'Exceltest': Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again.

Everything worked before I upgraded to Android Studio v3.5.2, tried all suggestions offered by AS but I'm having difficulty in trying to update manually, both the gradle upgrade and the tools upgrade. I'm very new to AS, I have looked at previous answers but they relate to much older versions or file systems do not exist in my version. Please can someone help?

Comment: What is the error message given by Gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote it in wrong place  `implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` remove this line from your gradle `build.gradle` below gradle classpath

Comment: Thank you to all who answered, yes this worked. Can I ask why AS built the Gradle with this line in the wrong place?

Comment: Your dependencies should be in your app level gradle file not project level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your project's build.gradle file. It should look like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine but,
**1**. Some Library you migrated into Androidx and some not so i request you to migrate your project's all library into androidx.
**2**. Remove implementation line from your project level gradle file or move it to App level gradle file.